# Javascript wait for a function response to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook

I am trying to ask a follow up question "quick reply" in a Facebook bot implementation. You can see the full app.js (sample file here): https://github.com/fbsamples/messenger-platform-samples/blob/master/node/app.js

When the 1) user enters a command -- e.g. "hello", after i send the user the relevant response -- 2) i want to ask a follow up question.. e.g. "Would you like to know about the weather today?"

```
case 'hello':
       sendHelloGenericReponse(senderID);
       sendWeatherQuickReplyQuestion(senderID); //only execute this after above is complete
       break;
```

I.e. i want to wait for 1 to complete before doing 2. However, for some reason the weather question always gets displayed to user first. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you using promises in your `sendHelloGenericReponse` and `sendWeatherQuickReplyQuestion` methods?

Answer (score 0):

wrap you function in setTimeout

```js
case 'hello':
   sendHelloGenericReponse(senderID);
   setTimeout(function(){
      sendWeatherQuickReplyQuestion(senderID);
   },0) //only execute this after above is complete
   break;
```

Comment: How does that help?

Comment: Same question as vlaz? :)

Comment: It will ensure to execute the current stack fully,then this method 'sendWeatherQuickReplyQuestion(senderID)'. Though it doesn't depend on the response of first method.

Comment: ok. so where does sendHelloGenericResponse(senderID) fit into this? Can you please write down what i should try in the case: block for this? thx.

Comment: Thanks.. tried it, still does not work for me. does not seem to work. sendWeatherQuickReply response is getting displayed to user before    sendHelloGenericReponse is displayed to user :(

Comment: You can look at this file here: https://github.com/fbsamples/messenger-platform-samples/blob/master/node/app.js. I am using that template for my code.

Comment: In  if (messageText) { -- you will be the case statements. I am essentially calling sendGenericMessage(senderID), sendQuickReply(senderID) from a new case for handling 'hello'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132127/discussion-between-chicagodude-and-ricky).